# Is there a simple way only output if variable in in a comma separated list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code. 
What I want to do is only show STAXCODE if the state is in this list. AL,FL,CO

```
<% @ship_states.each do |state| %>
  <%= state.STAXCODE %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
<% @ship_states.each do |state| %>
  <%= ['AL', 'FL', 'CO'].include?(state.STAXCODE) ? state.STAXCODE : nil  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: UPDATE: Your code did work. I found that the state codes in the database have a trailing space after each so 'FL' is actually 'FL '. Is there a good way to deal with that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, ``state.STAXCODE.strip`` should get rid of those spaces for you